# Why does Tomcat require multiple server cleans after mvn clean install?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

This routinely happens in eclipse after running a `mvn clean install`. I end up having to clean my tomcat server several times before the error below disappears.

Sorry for the lack of info, I don't know where to start. This isn't the only Java Stack, spring project using tomcat, that required this.

```
Publishing to Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost...' has encountered a problem.   

Publishing failed with multiple errors | 

<< Details
Publishing failed with multiple errors

File not found: F:\workspace\...\...\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources
    \META-INF\maven\com....\...\pom.properties.

F:\workspace\...\...\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven
    \com...\...\pom.properties 
    (The system cannot find the path specified)

File not found: F:\workspace\...\...\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF
    \maven\com....\...\pom.xml.

F:\workspace\...\...\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources
    \META-INF\maven\com....\...\pom.xml 
    (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any resource change happens eclipse will deploy the changes to the server. In your case partial update happens when you run the maven command.

Why are you running maven command when you have your project setup in eclipse?

Comment: I use maven from the cmd line or through eclipse using a Maven build command within eclipse's run configurations. I do this when I update my code through git and sometimes for local changes. Why not run a maven command when using eclipse? If that's the issue, then when should I? I should also mention that we don't have a central repository and so an update on a dependent project needs to be rebuilt with maven and then the project itself rebuilt to pull this latest snapshot from the local repo. I hope this makes sense and clarifies. I'd also appreciate any input/criticism on this process